# Minimum permissions to grant a SQL user ability to query and modify a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions

I want my Microsoft SQL user (devuser) to be able to be able:

- To create/delete/modify tables within a single database.
- To do all of this via MS SQL Server Management Studio including Query Analyzer.

Where do I go and what are minimum level of permissions I need to set for this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, just clarified. Thanks